# Outlook 2007 Truncates Long Messages using Windows 7 (but not XP Home Edition)

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2007

My co-workers and I discovered that on a couple Windows 7 machines with Outlook 2007 installed, long messages (certain error log reports) are truncated.  We did some testing and using Google Mail the full message is stored on the server.  My machine (Windows XP Home with Outlook 2007) displays the entire message.

Is there a setting (like Exchange Cache Mode) that can be causing this?  I looked through Outlook 2007 on all three machines and couldn't find a setting that might be causing this.  Any help is much appreciated.

My apologies...  I forgot to mention, we are all running Google Apps Sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change Google Apps Sync mailbox size.  Oddly, XP can keep the Google Apps Sync mailbox at 1 GB, but Windows 7 needs it at 4 GB or larger for the messages to not truncate.  Must be the way data handling is carried out in the two different operating systems.